# how to open new activity by clicking card view in fragments?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I've made a `CardView` in `Fragment`. But I also want my card to call another activity when user clicks on it.

I am posting part of my code below:

```
public class basic extends Fragment{

GridLayout  mainGrid;

    public basic() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basic, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".basic">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/maingrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:rowCount="5">

        <!-- Row1 -->

        <!-- column1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"

            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <!-- Row1 -->

        <!-- column1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"

            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row1 -->

        <!-- column1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"

            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row1 -->

        <!-- column1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"

            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/Aboutc"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>





    </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cardview card= v.findViewById(R.id.yourCardName);
 card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

You can also use this method inside adapter. If you use inside adapter

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Use this to start Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to use getActivity() before .startActivity();

```
Cardview card= v.findViewById(R.id.cardid);
     card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity();

                }
            })
```